# Assign a variable from py file to a label in kv file?

Tags: python, variables, kivy

I was wondering if there's a way that I can assign a variable that I've created in the .py file into a `Label` in the .kv file? The variable in question is `cart` which is set to 0 and I want to create a `Label` that updates when `cart` changes value. I've tried adding `root.cart` or `app.cart` to the text of Label but they don't seem to work. Any help would be really appreciated!

Here's a simple example code that I've created to reach my goal.

.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

cart = 0

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    def LasagneSmall(self, button):
        global cart
        cart = cart + 7
        print(cart)


    def sizeSelection(self):
        sizepopup = FloatLayout()
        sizepop = Popup(title="Format", separator_color=[0.6, 0, 0, 1], content=sizepopup,title_font=("Gothic"), size_hint=(0.6, 0.6))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Label(text="Choose a format", font_name="Gothic", pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0.4}))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Button(text="Small", font_name="Gothic", size_hint=(1, 0.15), pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0.6}, on_release = self.LasagneSmall ))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Button(text="Back", font_name="Gothic", size_hint=(0.8, 0.15), pos_hint={"x": 0.10, "y": 0}, on_release=sizepop.dismiss))
        sizepop.open()

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class exampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exampleApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
<WindowManager>:
    FirstScreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Add to cart"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25,"y":0.5}
            on_release:
                root.sizeSelection()
        Label:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a `global`, you should use a `NumericProperty` for the `cart` variable. If you reference a `Property` as the value for an attribute in `kv`, then `kv` will automatically set up bindings to update that attribute when the `Property` changes. Here is a slightly modified version of the `FirstScreen` class that uses a `Property` for cart:

```
# cart = 0

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    cart = NumericProperty(0)
    def LasagneSmall(self, button):
        # global cart
        self.cart += 7
        print(self.cart)
```

Then that `Property` can be referenced in the `kv`:

```
<WindowManager>:
    FirstScreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Add to cart"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25,"y":0.5}
            on_release:
                root.sizeSelection()
        Label:
            text: str(root.cart)   # references the cart property
            size_hint: 0.5,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25,"top":1}
```

Comment: This works nicely! Just one more thing. If I had multiple screens how would I be able to call the cart variable since cart is  defined inside the FirstScreen?

Comment: You could put the `cart` in the `App` class, and refer to it as `app.cart` in the `kv`.

Comment: Tried it. It is giving me an error 'FirstScreen' object has no attribute 'cart'. I also tried putting 'MyApp.cart' instead of 'self.cart' but it's giving me 'unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'kivy.properties.NumericProperty' and 'int'. I can't seem to figure out why.